# Adding a <dependency> to my Atlassian plugin's pom.xml causes a Spring BundleException with a Constraint violation

Tags: java, spring, osgi, confluence

I'm working on writing a plugin for Atlassian Confluence. I've had it working in a development environment for quite some time. But, when I package the plugin and deploye it into a test system the plugin fails to enable. I see the following cause / error message in the stack trace (included in entirety at the end of this question). I've formatted it for slightly easier reading:

```
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: 
    Constraint violation for package 'org.springframework.transaction' when resolving module 200.0 between existing import 0.org.springframework.transaction 
    BLAMED ON 
        [
            [200.0] package; 
            (&(package=org.springframework.transaction)(version>=0.0.0)(version<=0.0.0))
        ] 
        and uses constraint 4.0.org.springframework.transaction
    BLAMED ON 
        [
            [200.0] package;
            (package=org.springframework.jms.connection)
        ]
```

I'm having trouble understanding what this is trying to tell me. The Confluence OSGi container debugging information indicates the following for the packages mentioned:

0 - System Bundle

4 - Spring Framework

200 - com.foo.ConflunceJMSIntegration (my plugin)

I am suspect this has something to do with class loaders used by the various modules, but I just don't know how to interpret the message or what to do to resolve the problem.

### New information:

- The plugin works with Confluence 5.5.4 but fails with 5.6.4.
- I made a new empty generated plugin (atlas-create-confluence-plugin) and carefully added each of my dependencies to the pom.xml until I was able to produce the failure. The failure is clearly caused when I add this dependency:

  com.foo
      JMSTools
      1.0-SNAPSHOT
      
          
              org.slf4j
              slf4j-api
          
          
              javax.mail
              mail
          
          
              log4j
              log4j

This is a library I wrote. While it doesn't use Spring for configuration itself, some objects implement org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean and use org.springframework.util.StringUtils, so Spring is a legitimate requirement.

This is the dependency in JMSTools:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6.SEC02</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And.... now that I type this out I see that Confluence 5.6.4 uses org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6.SEC03-atlassian-6:compile.

I just tried changing the version JMSTools is using to 2.5.6.SEC03 and it still did not resolve the problem. Even if it did, I'd be concerned that future updates Confluence might update Spring and break things again. My library isn't dependent on a specific version of Spring, it simply needs to implement/use the class and interface I mentioned before.

My current suspicion is that org.apache.activemq:activemq-all (a dependency of JMSTools) may be referencing the org.springframework.jms.connection for some reason, somehow causing the conflict. But.... I just don't know (yet).

### Answers to Scott Dudley's questions:

#### (a) Confluence version:

5.6.4

#### (b) Dependency list from pom.xml (as printed by 'atlas-mvn dependency:tree'):

```
com.foo:ConflunceJMSIntegration:atlassian-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
|  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
+- com.atlassian.confluence:confluence:jar:5.6.4:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.security:atlassian-secure-xml:jar:3.2.3:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.crowd:embedded-crowd-api:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:provided
|  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-core:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-api:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-persistence-file:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-events:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.security:atlassian-secure-random:jar:3.2:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-integration-api:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.ip:atlassian-ip:jar:3.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-integration-seraph25:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-integration-client-common:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.crowd:embedded-crowd-spi:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-password-encoders:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.security:atlassian-password-encoder:jar:3.2:provided
|  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.crowd:atlassian-embedded-crowd-atlassian-user:jar:1.7.3:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.crowd:embedded-crowd-core:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-remote:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  |     \- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-integration-client-rest:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-persistence:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-ldap:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.confluence:confluence-upgrade:jar:5.6.4:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.gzipfilter:atlassian-gzipfilter:jar:1.23:provided
|  |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.gzipfilter:atlassian-flushable-gzipoutputstream:jar:1.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.analytics:analytics-api:jar:3.37:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.applinks:applinks-api:jar:4.2.3:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.applinks:applinks-spi:jar:4.2.3:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.applinks:applinks-host:jar:4.2.3:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.dragonfly:dragonfly-api:jar:1.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.dragonfly:dragonfly-spi:jar:1.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.dragonfly:dragonfly-core:jar:1.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.util.concurrent:atlassian-util-concurrent:jar:2.4.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.modzdetector:modz-detector:jar:0.8.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.mail:atlassian-mail:jar:2.5.0:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.velocity:atlassian-velocity:jar:1.3:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.core:atlassian-core:jar:4.6.11:provided
|  |  +- org.apache.sanselan:sanselan:jar:0.97-incubator:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.image:atlassian-image-consumer:jar:1.0.1:provided
|  |  \- javax.media:jai-core:jar:1.1.3:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.config:atlassian-config:jar:0.21:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.spring:atlassian-spring:jar:2.0.0:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.spring:atlassian-spring-hibernate2:jar:2.0.0:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.event:atlassian-event:jar:2.3.5:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.confluence:confluence-bucket:jar:5.6.4:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.hibernate:atlassian-hibernate2-extras:jar:4.1.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.xwork:atlassian-xwork-10:jar:1.17:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.xwork:atlassian-xwork-core:jar:1.17:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.profiling:atlassian-profiling:jar:1.9:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.threadlocal:atlassian-threadlocal:jar:1.4:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.trackback:atlassian-trackback:jar:0.10:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.extras:atlassian-extras-core:jar:3.2:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.extras:atlassian-extras-api:jar:3.2:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.extras:atlassian-extras-common:jar:3.2:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.extras:atlassian-extras-legacy:jar:3.2:provided
|  |  |  \- com.atlassian.extras:atlassian-extras-decoder-api:jar:3.2:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.extras:atlassian-extras-decoder-v2:jar:3.2:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.johnson:atlassian-johnson:jar:0.10:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.json:atlassian-json-jsonorg:jar:0.9:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.json:atlassian-json-api:jar:0.9:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-core:jar:3.2.8:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.annotations:atlassian-annotations:jar:0.7:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-servlet:jar:3.2.8:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webfragment:jar:3.0.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webresource:jar:3.1.1-PLUGWEB-85-m05:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webresource-common:jar:3.0.0:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-webresource-api:jar:3.1.1-PLUGWEB-85-m05:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.html:atlassian-html-encoder:jar:1.4:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi:jar:3.2.8:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi-events:jar:3.2.8:provided
|  |  +- biz.aQute:bndlib:jar:1.43.0-atlassian-1:provided
|  |  +- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.framework:jar:3.0.2:provided
|  |  \- org.twdata.pkgscanner:package-scanner:jar:0.9.5:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-schema:jar:3.2.8:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-spring:jar:3.2.8:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-spring-interceptor-adapter-spi:jar:1.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.bandana:atlassian-bandana:jar:3.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.user:atlassian-user:jar:3.0:provided
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-dao:jar:2.0.6:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.renderer:atlassian-renderer-legacy:jar:6.2.10:provided
|  |  \- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.7:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.bonnie:atlassian-bonnie:jar:6.1.2:provided
|  |  +- com.atlassian.bonnie:lucene-upgrader:jar:lucene36:1.0:provided
|  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:1.7.1:provided
|  |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:1.7.1:provided
|  |  |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.7.1:provided
|  |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:3.8:provided
|  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.50:provided
|  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:jar:1.50:provided
|  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.50:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.jdk.utilities:atlassian-jdk-utilities:jar:0.4:provided
|  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.seraph:atlassian-seraph:jar:3.0.0:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.security:atlassian-cookie-tools:jar:3.2.3:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps:atlassian-trusted-apps-core:jar:3.0.8:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps:atlassian-trusted-apps-seraph-integration:jar:3.0.8:provided
|  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:provided
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:provided
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:provided
|  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:provided
|  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:provided
|  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
|  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:provided
|  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:provided
|  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:provided
|  +- hibernate:hibernate:jar:2.1.8-atlassian-27:provided
|  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:provided
|  |  \- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:provided
|  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.4-full:provided
|  +- odmg:odmg:jar:3.0:provided
|  +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:provided
|  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:provided
|  +- com.sun:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:provided
|  +- com.sun:jai_codec:jar:1.1.3:provided
|  +- opensymphony:webwork:jar:2.1.5-atlassian-2:provided
|  +- opensymphony:xwork:jar:1.0.3.6:provided
|  +- ognl:ognl:jar:2.6.5-atlassian-2:provided
|  +- opensymphony:oscore:jar:2.2.7-atlassian-1:provided
|  +- oscache:oscache:jar:2.2:provided
|  +- osuser:osuser:jar:atl.user:provided
|  +- opensymphony:propertyset:jar:1.3-21Nov03:provided
|  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.4-atlassian-1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.soy:soy-template-renderer-api:jar:2.8.0:provided
|  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:provided
|  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5:provided
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6.SEC03-atlassian-6:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.5.6.SEC03:provided
|  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.5.6.SEC03:provided
|  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:provided
|  +- org.springframework:spring-hibernate2:jar:2.5.6-atlassian-1:provided
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:2.5.6:provided
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6.SEC03:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:2.5.6.SEC03:provided
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6.SEC03:provided
|  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:2.5.6.SEC03:provided
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:2.5.6.SEC03:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.paddle:atlassian-paddle:jar:5:provided
|  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.0:provided
|  +- net.sf.ldaptemplate:ldaptemplate:jar:1.0.1:provided
|  +- opensymphony:sitemesh:jar:2.5-atlassian-6:provided
|  +- velocity-tools:velocity-tools:jar:view-1.1:provided
|  +- radeox:radeox:jar:1.0b2-forked-22Apr2004:provided
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.4.0:provided
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.4.0:provided
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-kuromoji:jar:4.4.0:provided
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:4.4.0:provided
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:4.4.0:provided
|  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:4.4.0:provided
|  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.4.0:provided
|  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:4.4.0:provided
|  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:4.4.0:provided
|  |     \- jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp:jar:1.4:provided
|  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.5:provided
|  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.5:provided
|  |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:provided
|  +- org.hibernate:jtidy:jar:r8-20060801:provided
|  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:1.8.0:provided
|  +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.0:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.hsqldb:atlassian-hsqdlb-server-integration:jar:1.1.0:provided
|  +- rome:rome:jar:1.0:provided
|  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:provided
|  +- commons-jrcs:commons-jrcs:jar:diff-0.1.7:provided
|  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:provided
|  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:provided
|  +- xmlrpc:xmlrpc:jar:2.0+xmlrpc61.1+sbfix:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.xmlrpc:xmlrpc-supplementary-character-support:jar:0.2:provided
|  +- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:provided
|  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:provided
|  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:provided
|  +- slide:slide:jar:2.1:provided
|  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.1.1:provided
|  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O:provided
|  +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.0:provided
|  |  \- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.0:provided
|  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:provided
|  +- com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha-all:jar:1.0-RC6:provided
|  |  \- concurrent:concurrent:jar:1.3.4:provided
|  +- org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:jar:4.0.4:provided
|  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:provided
|  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:provided
|  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.9-atlassian-1:provided
|  +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-core:jar:1.2.6:provided
|  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:provided
|  |  \- org.apache.ws.commons:XmlSchema:jar:1.1:provided
|  +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-aegis:jar:1.2.6:provided
|  |  \- net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20040917:provided
|  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.cache:atlassian-cache-api:jar:2.3.4:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.cache:atlassian-cache-memory:jar:2.3.4:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.cache:atlassian-cache-common-impl:jar:2.3.4:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.beehive:beehive-api:jar:0.1.3:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.sal:sal-spi:jar:2.12.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.sal:sal-spring:jar:2.12.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.sal:sal-api:jar:2.12.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.confluence:confluence-java-api:jar:5.6.4:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.confluence:confluence-rest-api:jar:5.6.4:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.confluence:confluence-rest-serialization:jar:5.6.4:provided
|  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.1:provided
|  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.1:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.activeobjects:activeobjects-dbex:jar:0.28.2:provided
|  |  \- com.atlassian.activeobjects:activeobjects-spi:jar:0.28.2:provided
|  +- org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:jar:1.4.2-atlassian-13:provided
|  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:provided
|  |     +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:provided
|  |     \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:provided
|  +- org.outerj.daisy:daisydiff:jar:1.1-atlassian-5:provided
|  |  \- org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:20070801:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.velocity.htmlsafe:velocity-htmlsafe:jar:1.2-fixedscm:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.botocss:botocss-core:jar:4.3:provided
|  |  +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.7.2:provided
|  |  +- net.sourceforge.cssbox:jstyleparser:jar:1.13-atlassian-2:provided
|  |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:provided
|  |     +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:provided
|  |     \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:provided
|  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.fugue:fugue:jar:1.1:provided
|  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.6:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.http:atlassian-http:jar:0.0.8.8:provided
|  +- org.javasimon:javasimon-core:jar:3.4.0:provided
|  \- com.atlassian.tenancy:atlassian-tenancy-api:jar:1.4.1:provided
+- com.atlassian.confluence.plugins:confluence-rpc-plugin:jar:5.6.4:provided
+- com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner:jar:1.2.0:test
+- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:provided
+- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2:provided
+- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test
+- com.foo:JMSTools:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:jar:5.10.0:compile
|  \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-jaas:jar:5.10.0:compile
+- com.atlassian.confluence.plugins:confluence-space-ia:jar:8.3:provided
+- com.atlassian.activeobjects:activeobjects-core:jar:0.25.2:provided
|  \- net.java.dev.activeobjects:activeobjects:jar:0.25.2:provided
+- com.atlassian.confluence.plugins:doctheme:jar:5.6.3:provided
+- com.atlassian.applinks:applinks-core:jar:2.5.12:provided
+- com.atlassian.applinks:applinks-plugin:jar:4.1.2:provided
+- com.atlassian.plugins.rest:atlassian-rest-common:jar:1.0.2:provided
|  +- com.atlassian.plugins.rest:com.atlassian.jersey-library:pom:1.0.2:provided
|  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.0.3:provided
|  |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.0.3:provided
|  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.0.3:provided
|  |     +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.0.1:provided
|  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-asl:jar:0.9.4:provided
|  \- net.sourceforge.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.2:provided
+- org.apache.wink:wink-client:jar:1.1.3-incubating:test
|  +- org.apache.wink:wink-common:jar:1.1.3-incubating:test
|  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.1_spec:jar:1.0:test
|  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.1.1:test
|  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1:test
|  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1:test
+- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.4.9:test
|  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.4.9:test
|     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.4.9:test
|     |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.14.0-GA:test
|     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.4.9:test
|        \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:test
\- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.4.9:test
   \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.4.9:test
```

#### (c) Component Imports:

**From atlassian-plugin.xml:**

```
<component-import key="transactionTemplate" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.transaction.TransactionTemplate"/>
<component-import key="sidebar-link-service"
                  interface="com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.ia.service.SidebarLinkService"/>
<component-import key="userManager" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.user.UserManager"/>
<component-import key="systemTemplateManager" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SystemTemplateManager"/>
<component-import key="fileUploadManager" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.confluence.pages.FileUploadManager"/>
<component-import key="entityLinkService" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.applinks.spi.link.MutatingEntityLinkService"/>
<component-import key="applicationLinkService" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.applinks.api.ApplicationLinkService"/>
<component-import key="typeAccessor" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.applinks.spi.util.TypeAccessor"/>
<component-import key="entityLinkBuilderFactory" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.applinks.spi.link.EntityLinkBuilderFactory"/>
<component-import key="applicationProperties" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties"/>
<component-import key="licenseService" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.confluence.license.LicenseService"/>
<component-import key="i18nResolver" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.message.I18nResolver"/>
<component-import key="loginUriProvider" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.auth.LoginUriProvider"/>
<component-import key="soyTemplateRenderer" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.soy.renderer.SoyTemplateRenderer" />
<component-import name="Plugin Settings Factory" key="pluginSettingsFactory" 
                  interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.pluginsettings.PluginSettingsFactory"/>
```

**From META-INF/spring/atlassian-plugin-context.xml:**

```
<osgi:reference id="transactionTemplate"
                interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.transaction.TransactionTemplate" />
<osgi:reference id="sidebarLinkService"
                interface="com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.ia.service.SidebarLinkService" />
<osgi:reference id="userManager"
                interface="com.atlassian.user.UserManager" />
<osgi:reference id="systemTemplateManager"
                interface="com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SystemTemplateManager" />
<osgi:reference id="fileUploadManager"
                interface="com.atlassian.confluence.pages.FileUploadManager" />
<osgi:reference id="entityLinkService"
                interface="com.atlassian.applinks.spi.link.MutatingEntityLinkService"/>
<osgi:reference id="applicationLinkService"
                interface="com.atlassian.applinks.api.ApplicationLinkService"/>
<osgi:reference id="typeAccessor"
                interface="com.atlassian.applinks.spi.util.TypeAccessor"/>
<osgi:reference id="entityLinkBuilderFactory"
                interface="com.atlassian.applinks.spi.link.EntityLinkBuilderFactory"/>
<osgi:reference id="pluginSettingsFactory"
                interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.pluginsettings.PluginSettingsFactory" />
<osgi:reference id="spaceManager"
                interface="com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SpaceManager" />
<osgi:reference id="pageManager"
                interface="com.atlassian.confluence.pages.PageManager" />
```

Note: I need to check to make sure that I still need all of these imports / references. I'm also not sure if I need to have the component-import in the atlassian-plugin.xml to reference them in the atlassian-plugin-context.xml. If not, I may be able to clean up these lists a bit.

#### (d) components where public=true:

```
<component key="confluence-event-listener" class="com.foo.confluence.ConfluenceJMSAnnouncerImpl"
           name="Confluence Event Listener" i18n-name-key="confluence-event-listener.name" public="true">
    <description key="confluence-event-listener.description">The confluence event listener Impl Plugin</description>
    <interface>com.foo.confluence.ConfluenceJMSAnnouncer</interface>
</component>
```

Note: I suspect this doesn't need to be public.

Second note: I have 30 beans configured in the atlassian-plugin-context.xml. The only one I expose is:

```
<osgi:service interface="com.foo.confluence.ConfluenceService" ref="confluenceService"/>
```

### Full stack trace:

```
2014-10-30 09:29:25,451 ERROR [main] [plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin] enableInternal Detected an error (BundleException) enabling the plugin 'com.foo.ConflunceJMSIntegration' : Constraint violation for package 'org.springframework.transaction' when resolving module 201.0 between existing import 0.org.springframework.transaction BLAMED ON [[201.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.transaction)(version>=0.0.0)(version<=0.0.0))] and uses constraint 4.0.org.springframework.transaction BLAMED ON [[201.0] package; (package=org.springframework.jms.connection)].  This error usually occurs when your plugin imports a package from another bundle with a specific version constraint and either the bundle providing that package doesn't meet those version constraints, or there is no bundle available that provides the specified package. For more details on how to fix this, see https://developer.atlassian.com/x/mQAN
2014-10-30 09:29:25,452 WARN [main] [atlassian.plugin.impl.AbstractPlugin] enable Unable to enable plugin 'com.foo.ConflunceJMSIntegration'
2014-10-30 09:29:25,454 WARN [main] [atlassian.plugin.impl.AbstractPlugin] enable Because of this exception
com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.container.OsgiContainerException: Cannot start plugin: com.foo.ConflunceJMSIntegration
    at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin.enableInternal(OsgiPlugin.java:479)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.impl.AbstractPlugin.enable(AbstractPlugin.java:310)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.impl.AbstractDelegatingPlugin.enable(AbstractDelegatingPlugin.java:242)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.PluginEnabler.actualEnable(PluginEnabler.java:136)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.PluginEnabler.enable(PluginEnabler.java:104)
.... had to remove detail to trim length of question ....
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Constraint violation for package 'org.springframework.transaction' when resolving module 201.0 between existing import 0.org.springframework.transaction BLAMED ON [[201.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.transaction)(version>=0.0.0)(version<=0.0.0))] and uses constraint 4.0.org.springframework.transaction BLAMED ON [[201.0] package; (package=org.springframework.jms.connection)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3415)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1709)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:905)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:892)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin.enableInternal(OsgiPlugin.java:456)
    ... 33 more
2014-10-30 09:29:25,455 ERROR [main] [atlassian.plugin.manager.PluginEnabler] actualEnable Unable to enable plugin com.foo.ConflunceJMSIntegration
com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.container.OsgiContainerException: Cannot start plugin: com.foo.ConflunceJMSIntegration
    at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin.enableInternal(OsgiPlugin.java:479)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.impl.AbstractPlugin.enable(AbstractPlugin.java:310)
.... had to remove detail to trim length of question ....
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Constraint violation for package 'org.springframework.transaction' when resolving module 201.0 between existing import 0.org.springframework.transaction BLAMED ON [[201.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.transaction)(version>=0.0.0)(version<=0.0.0))] and uses constraint 4.0.org.springframework.transaction BLAMED ON [[201.0] package; (package=org.springframework.jms.connection)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3415)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1709)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:905)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:892)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin.enableInternal(OsgiPlugin.java:456)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Do you have any explicit OSGi import instructions in your pom.xml or atlassian-plugins.xml? If so, can you please post them? (Also, you seem to have omitted the stack trace at the end of the post.) My read of the error is that v4 of the Spring transaction package is supplied, but perhaps you have supplied a constraint of "[0.0.0,0.0.0]" that specifically excludes it.

Comment: D'oh, I did forget the stack trace. Sorry about that. (I'll update the question once I get my app back to a point where I get this specific error again.) I do not have any OSGi import instructions in either my pom.xml or atlassian-plugins.xml. From what I can tell, Confluence itself loads (provides? I'm not sure of the terminology here) org.springframework.transaction in the system bundle and the spring framework bundle. They do have different versions. Note, I think that the 4.0.org.springframework.transaction refers to bundle 4, not version 4.

Comment: Oh—I think you're right about the "4". If you don't supply specific OSGi bundle instructions, then Confluence builds them automatically on plugin install by scanning your JAR. On top of the stack trace, can you please also post: (a) your Confluence version, (b) your `<dependency>` list from your pom.xml,  (c) `<component-import>`s from your atlassian-plugin.xml, and (d) any `<component>` from your atlassian-plugin.xml where `public=true`?

Comment: I notice also the "uses constraint" mention in the error. This one is new OSGi territory for me too, but this looks related: http://njbartlett.name/2011/09/02/uses-constraints.html

Comment: Scott, I've edited the question to add new information and to answer your questions. I'll give that link a read too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the reason for having your own META-INF/spring/atlassian-plugin-context.xml file? (The `component-import` in your atlassian-plugin.xml will automatically take care of imports for the named components. Additionally, every `component` of your own in atlassian-plugin.xml is automatically instantiated as a bean, whether or not it's public.) Are you doing anything else with that requires this file?

Comment: Also, did your empty atlas-create-confluence-plugin plugin have anything in META-INF/spring? Did you change anything in the project except the pom? (A certain amount of ninja action involves anything in that folder, since Confluence does its own relatively-obscure OSGi transformation at runtime when loading the plugin, and placing certain files or configuring certain attributes there can sometimes inhibit the behavior you would otherwise expect.)

Comment: One hunch: if just adding the dep to the pom.xml causes problems, try setting extractDependencies=false in the confluence-plugin config, like shown below. After making this edit, make sure to nuke target/classes before doing a full rebuild. `<plugin><groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-confluence-plugin</artifactId><version>x.y.z</version>[...]<configuration> [...] <extractDependencies>false</extractDependencies></configuration></plugin>`

Comment: I am using the atlassian-plugin-context.xml because I use spring xml to configure several classes in ways that (I think) you can't using atlassian-plugin.xml. For example, I have 13 instances of com.foo.jms.Consumer configured to listen for different JMS messages. Those are wired to call methods on configured message handlers. I don't know of a way to do this type of config using the atlassian-plugin.xml XML alone.

Comment: No, my empty atlas-create-confluence-plugin plugin did not have anything META-INF/spring. I only changed the pom.xml dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean regarding the use of extractDependencies=false. I'm researching that now and will report back once I've figured it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63951/discussion-between-scott-dudley-and-doug-hughes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely adding `<dependency>` entries to the `pom.xml` in an otherwise-empty plugin should not generally cause OSGi errors on plugin load, since Confluence should not be trying to import external packages merely based on the presence of a dependency.

My suspicion (confirmed in the chat thread) is that one of your dependencies is including some sort of Spring instructions that is confusing Confluence on plugin load. When a plugin is built using the defaults, the plugin SDK will automatically un-JAR all of the dependencies and include the resulting set of files in the main plugin JAR.

If one of your library dependencies inadvertently included Spring-related data in `META-INF/spring` or elsewhere, this would get intermingled with your own plugin's Spring configuration, which can wreak havoc.

The best way to solve this is to disable dependency extraction. This means that instead of un-JARring all of your dependencies and dumping them in the same JAR as your plugin, the dependencies are left in their source JARs and those JARs are included directly in `META-INF/lib`. Even if the dependencies do declare some rogue Spring instructions, they will remain in their own JAR and they will not be processed by Confluence when loading your plugin.

To disable the extraction of dependencies, you will want to set extractDependencies to false in the confluence-maven-plugin section of your `pom.xml`, as shown below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-conflue‌​‌​nce-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>x.y.z</version>
    [...]
    <configuration>
        [...]
        <extractDependencies>false</extractDependencies>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Scott has written a very nice description of what happens here. I also recommend switching extractDependencies to false just so there is not so much clutter appearing in your jar. Apparently extracting dependencies speeds up the start time of your plugin, but damn, it makes things untidy as well as the unfortunate effect of sometimes messing with Spring configuration.